# Iostream in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I am a beginner c++ programmer, and have recently upgraded to windows 10 and installed the new Visual Studio 2015. However whenever I use iostream

```
#include <iostream>
```

and attempt to compile the code, it returns 289 Errors. From my understanding cmath, and math.h are conflicting with re definitions. Here is the entirety of the code in my program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    return(0);
}
```

And when this is run, the output from Visual Studio 2015 is:

```
 1>------ Build started: Project: Test, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
 1>  main.cpp
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(33): error C2995: '_Ty _Pow_int(_Ty,int) throw()': function template has already been defined
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1013): note: see declaration of '_Pow_int'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(36): error C2084: function 'double abs(double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1025): note: see previous definition of 'abs'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(41): error C2084: function 'double pow(double,int) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1027): note: see previous definition of 'pow'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(46): error C2084: function 'float abs(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1029): note: see previous definition of 'abs'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(51): error C2084: function 'float acos(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1031): note: see previous definition of 'acos'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(56): error C2084: function 'float acosh(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1033): note: see previous definition of 'acosh'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(61): error C2084: function 'float asin(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1035): note: see previous definition of 'asin'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(66): error C2084: function 'float asinh(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1037): note: see previous definition of 'asinh'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(71): error C2084: function 'float atan(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1039): note: see previous definition of 'atan'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(76): error C2084: function 'float atanh(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1041): note: see previous definition of 'atanh'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(81): error C2084: function 'float atan2(float,float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1043): note: see previous definition of 'atan2'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(86): error C2084: function 'float cbrt(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1045): note: see previous definition of 'cbrt'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(91): error C2084: function 'float ceil(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1047): note: see previous definition of 'ceil'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(97): error C2084: function 'float copysign(float,float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1049): note: see previous definition of 'copysign'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(102): error C2084: function 'float cos(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1051): note: see previous definition of 'cos'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(107): error C2084: function 'float cosh(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1053): note: see previous definition of 'cosh'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(112): error C2084: function 'float erf(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1055): note: see previous definition of 'erf'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(117): error C2084: function 'float erfc(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1057): note: see previous definition of 'erfc'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(122): error C2084: function 'float exp(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1059): note: see previous definition of 'exp'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(127): error C2084: function 'float exp2(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1061): note: see previous definition of 'exp2'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(132): error C2084: function 'float expm1(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1063): note: see previous definition of 'expm1'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(137): error C2084: function 'float fabs(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1065): note: see previous definition of 'fabs'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(142): error C2084: function 'float fdim(float,float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1067): note: see previous definition of 'fdim'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(147): error C2084: function 'float floor(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1069): note: see previous definition of 'floor'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(153): error C2084: function 'float fma(float,float,float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1071): note: see previous definition of 'fma'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(158): error C2084: function 'float fmax(float,float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1073): note: see previous definition of 'fmax'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(163): error C2084: function 'float fmin(float,float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1075): note: see previous definition of 'fmin'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(168): error C2084: function 'float fmod(float,float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1077): note: see previous definition of 'fmod'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(173): error C2084: function 'float frexp(float,int *) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1079): note: see previous definition of 'frexp'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(178): error C2084: function 'float hypot(float,float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1081): note: see previous definition of 'hypot'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(183): error C2084: function 'int ilogb(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1083): note: see previous definition of 'ilogb'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(188): error C2084: function 'float ldexp(float,int) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1085): note: see previous definition of 'ldexp'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(193): error C2084: function 'float lgamma(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1087): note: see previous definition of 'lgamma'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(198): error C2084: function '__int64 llrint(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1089): note: see previous definition of 'llrint'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(203): error C2084: function '__int64 llround(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1091): note: see previous definition of 'llround'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(208): error C2084: function 'float log(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1093): note: see previous definition of 'log'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(213): error C2084: function 'float log10(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1095): note: see previous definition of 'log10'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(218): error C2084: function 'float log1p(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1097): note: see previous definition of 'log1p'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(223): error C2084: function 'float log2(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1099): note: see previous definition of 'log2'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(228): error C2084: function 'float logb(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1101): note: see previous definition of 'logb'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(233): error C2084: function 'long lrint(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1103): note: see previous definition of 'lrint'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(238): error C2084: function 'long lround(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1105): note: see previous definition of 'lround'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(243): error C2084: function 'float modf(float,float *) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1107): note: see previous definition of 'modf'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(248): error C2084: function 'float nearbyint(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1109): note: see previous definition of 'nearbyint'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(253): error C2084: function 'float nextafter(float,float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1111): note: see previous definition of 'nextafter'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(259): error C2084: function 'float nexttoward(float,long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1113): note: see previous definition of 'nexttoward'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(265): error C2084: function 'float pow(float,float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1115): note: see previous definition of 'pow'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(270): error C2084: function 'float pow(float,int) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1117): note: see previous definition of 'pow'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(275): error C2084: function 'float remainder(float,float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1119): note: see previous definition of 'remainder'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(281): error C2084: function 'float remquo(float,float,int *) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1121): note: see previous definition of 'remquo'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(286): error C2084: function 'float rint(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1123): note: see previous definition of 'rint'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(291): error C2084: function 'float round(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1125): note: see previous definition of 'round'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(296): error C2084: function 'float scalbln(float,long) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1127): note: see previous definition of 'scalbln'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(301): error C2084: function 'float scalbn(float,int) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1129): note: see previous definition of 'scalbn'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(306): error C2084: function 'float sin(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1131): note: see previous definition of 'sin'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(311): error C2084: function 'float sinh(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1133): note: see previous definition of 'sinh'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(316): error C2084: function 'float sqrt(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1135): note: see previous definition of 'sqrt'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(321): error C2084: function 'float tan(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1137): note: see previous definition of 'tan'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(326): error C2084: function 'float tanh(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1139): note: see previous definition of 'tanh'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(331): error C2084: function 'float tgamma(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1141): note: see previous definition of 'tgamma'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(336): error C2084: function 'float trunc(float) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1143): note: see previous definition of 'trunc'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(341): error C2084: function 'long double abs(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1145): note: see previous definition of 'abs'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(346): error C2084: function 'long double acos(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1147): note: see previous definition of 'acos'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(351): error C2084: function 'long double acosh(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1149): note: see previous definition of 'acosh'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(356): error C2084: function 'long double asin(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1151): note: see previous definition of 'asin'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(361): error C2084: function 'long double asinh(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1153): note: see previous definition of 'asinh'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(366): error C2084: function 'long double atan(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1155): note: see previous definition of 'atan'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(371): error C2084: function 'long double atanh(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1157): note: see previous definition of 'atanh'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(377): error C2084: function 'long double atan2(long double,long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1159): note: see previous definition of 'atan2'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(382): error C2084: function 'long double cbrt(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1161): note: see previous definition of 'cbrt'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(387): error C2084: function 'long double ceil(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1163): note: see previous definition of 'ceil'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(393): error C2084: function 'long double copysign(long double,long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1165): note: see previous definition of 'copysign'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(398): error C2084: function 'long double cos(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1167): note: see previous definition of 'cos'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(403): error C2084: function 'long double cosh(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1169): note: see previous definition of 'cosh'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(408): error C2084: function 'long double erf(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1171): note: see previous definition of 'erf'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(413): error C2084: function 'long double erfc(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1173): note: see previous definition of 'erfc'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(418): error C2084: function 'long double exp(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1175): note: see previous definition of 'exp'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(423): error C2084: function 'long double exp2(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1177): note: see previous definition of 'exp2'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(428): error C2084: function 'long double expm1(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1179): note: see previous definition of 'expm1'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(433): error C2084: function 'long double fabs(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1181): note: see previous definition of 'fabs'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(439): error C2084: function 'long double fdim(long double,long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1183): note: see previous definition of 'fdim'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(444): error C2084: function 'long double floor(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1185): note: see previous definition of 'floor'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(450): error C2084: function 'long double fma(long double,long double,long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1187): note: see previous definition of 'fma'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(456): error C2084: function 'long double fmax(long double,long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1189): note: see previous definition of 'fmax'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(462): error C2084: function 'long double fmin(long double,long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1191): note: see previous definition of 'fmin'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(468): error C2084: function 'long double fmod(long double,long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1193): note: see previous definition of 'fmod'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(474): error C2084: function 'long double frexp(long double,int *) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1195): note: see previous definition of 'frexp'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(480): error C2084: function 'long double hypot(long double,long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1197): note: see previous definition of 'hypot'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(485): error C2084: function 'int ilogb(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1199): note: see previous definition of 'ilogb'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(491): error C2084: function 'long double ldexp(long double,int) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1201): note: see previous definition of 'ldexp'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(496): error C2084: function 'long double lgamma(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1203): note: see previous definition of 'lgamma'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(501): error C2084: function '__int64 llrint(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1205): note: see previous definition of 'llrint'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(506): error C2084: function '__int64 llround(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1207): note: see previous definition of 'llround'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(511): error C2084: function 'long double log(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1209): note: see previous definition of 'log'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(516): error C2084: function 'long double log10(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1211): note: see previous definition of 'log10'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(521): error C2084: function 'long double log1p(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1213): note: see previous definition of 'log1p'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(526): error C2084: function 'long double log2(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1215): note: see previous definition of 'log2'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(531): error C2084: function 'long double logb(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1217): note: see previous definition of 'logb'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(536): error C2084: function 'long lrint(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1219): note: see previous definition of 'lrint'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(541): error C2084: function 'long lround(long double) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1221): note: see previous definition of 'lround'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(547): error C2084: function 'long double modf(long double,long double *) throw()' already has a body
 1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\math.h(1223): note: see previous definition of 'modf'
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(547): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
 ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I would appreciate if anyone had suggestions for how to resolve this problem.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: You don't need to put the complete list of errors into your question, which makes it hard to read. It very much looks like a problem, that you have installed concurrent versions of VS now on your system. Try to deinstall the older version, before installing the latest.

Comment: They moved functions from one header to another- it seems that they're picking up the wrong versions of the headers.

Comment: Did you maybe install 2015 RTM into the same directory without removing the 2015 RC/preview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your toolchain is completely broken. I suggest removing then re-installing Visual Studio.

Comment: I uninstalled both versions of visual studio and reinstalled visual studio 2015, and it seems to be working properly now. Thanks